# Why does the ROC calculation for sklearn require the "class with the greater label"?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, roc, resnet

I am trying to use sklearn's ROC function. As input, it asks that the "the probability of the class with the “greater label” should be provided. My model is a Resnet18 with a fully connected layer with 2 nodes for binary classification. Though the outputs of the model are not "probabilities", I thought I should be able to use them for ROC, and that either node's output should work since they should be roughly complementary. However, I get different results for each.[image]

Why should I get a different ROC for each node's output? It seems to work as expected for the "1" class, but I don't see why that should be necessary.

sklearn documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#roc-metrics

Answer (score -1):

I realize my mistake. I was feeding in the same labels for each node's ROC calculation. Once I flipped the labels for the "0" case, I got a similar ROC as for "1". *Still, I'm curious if there's any difference for using my outputs vs probabilities if anyone can help there.*

Comment: Please do not use the answer space for "follow-up" questions; either delete this thread and open a new one, or edit it (even completely) to update it with your new question. As it is, your answer is highly unlikely to be of any help for others in the future (which is what SO is actually all about).